# Angular textarea validation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I have a textarea in my app like so:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="bioBackground" ng-model="obj.background" value="obj.background" ng-change="autosave()" maxlength="1500" required></textarea>
```

This is a **required** field and as you can see I have added a required tag in the code. But this required tag is causing errors with Angular.

For example:

If I type in the field and backspace and remove all the text it removes the object from the scope. see example below:

**Before Backspacing**

You can see background variable is in the scope.

[image]

**After backspacing and removing the text:**

You can see the background variable is gone from scope.

[image]

**This only happens if I use required tag. If I don't use the required tag it works fine and even after removing all the text the background variable stays within the scope.**

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is that object, which contains `experience` and `background`, being created in your controller?

Comment: @KreepN yes, like so `$scope.obj = {}`

Comment: Just checked it out myself, and that is some crazy stuff. Can't find any documentation on said problem either. Hope someone else has some insight

Comment: @KreepN any recommendations? Im might have validate my fields on submission in the controller rather then the front-end.

Comment: I guess it depends on your end goal, I see this as more of an interesting behavior with angular. I mean, even if it gets removed from scope, the form should not be able to be submitted without providing you a value in the text area. The box in question should remain red.

Comment: @KreepN I think the particular problem with me is that I counting characters in the textarea as the user types as I have limited the amount characters to be entered. And when I backspace and remove all the data in field I get a console log error saying `cannot read property length of undefined` because the variable `background` now does not exist in the scope. Ive removed the character count function for now and just set a `maxlength` property on the textarea.

Comment: Makes sense, although I'd just keep the function and add a simple `if(obj.Background) {}` before the length call and you'd be fine.

Comment: @KreepN thanks mate! I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

its working , background is undefined while remove all text using backspace.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.obj = {
"experience":{
"field0":"asdf",
"field1":"asss"
},
"background":""
};
console.log($scope.obj);
$scope.autosave=function(){
 console.log($scope.obj); 
  
}

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="bioBackground" ng-model="obj.background" value="obj.background" ng-change="autosave()" maxlength="1500" required></textarea>
  </body>

</html>
```